# Revision history for migrated post is not visible in app

Tags: bug, migration, ios-app, revisions-list

[Revision history](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/647023/revisions) for migrated post is not visible in the iOS app:

> [image: no history]

But in web I can see it:

> [image: web]

I'm not sure, but probably this happened due to the post deletion (not only migration). I know that API can't work with deleted posts. But revision is still accessible when opening in browser private mode (i.e. if post were deleted I would see 404).

- App Version: 1.6.5.1
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: This is another one of those things that can't ever change unless the API gets support for viewing deleted content. We don't currently have any plans for making that happen.

Comment: @animuson is it normal that I can see revision history of deleted post even without 10k rep?

Comment: You can always see the revision history for a migrated post because it could potentially contain extra information (the history doesn't get migrated with it).

Comment: @animuson should this question be tagged [tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: I've closed this as "no longer reproducible" since the mobile app stopped being supported years ago (so this will never get fixed).